# Problem with app update yml files is not generated in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I have a problem with the auto-update of electron app,
After I finished all the app parts and I am trying to push it to my custom update server , I found this error message in my logger :

```
Error unknown ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\{appPath}\{appName}\resources\app-update.yml'
```

and here is my package.json build configuration

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.server.app",
    "copyright": "Copyright company name",
    "generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels": true,
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": "dmg",
      "artifactName": "appName.dmg",
      "icon": "build/icon.icns"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "background": "build/i-bg.tif",
      "icon": "build/setup.icns",
      "iconSize": 80,
      "title": "${productName}-${version}",
      "window": {
        "width": 540,
        "height": 380
      }
    },
    "nsis": {
      "artifactName": "${productName}-Setup-${version}.${ext}",
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "installerIcon": "build/setup.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "build/setup.ico",
      "installerHeader": "build/installerHeader.bmp",
      "installerSidebar": "build/installerSidebar.bmp",
      "runAfterFinish": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": "always",
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
      "shortcutName": "AppName",
      "publish": [{
        "provider": "generic",
        "url": "https://my-update-server/path"
      }]
    },
    "extraFiles": [
      "data",
      "templates"
    ]
  },
  "publish": [{
    "provider": "generic",
    "url": "https://my-update-server/path"
  }],
```

and here is the code for triggering the auto-update

```
//-----------------------------------------------
// Auto-Update event listening 
//-----------------------------------------------

autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {
  splashLoadingStatus(`Checking for ${appName} update ...`);
})

autoUpdater.on('update-available',(info) => {
  splashLoadingStatus(`${appName} new update available.`);
})

autoUpdater.on('update-progress',(progInfo) => {
  splashLoadingStatus(`Download speed: ${progInfo.bytesPerSecond} - Download ${progInfo.percent}% (${progInfo.transferred}/${progInfo.total})`);
})

autoUpdater.on('error' , (error) => {
  dialog.showErrorBox('Error', error.message);
})

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (info) => {
  const message = {
    type: 'info',
    buttons: ['Restart', 'Update'],
    title: `${appName} Update`,
    detail: `A new version has been downloaded. Restart ${appName} to apply the updates.`
  }

  dialog.showMessageBox(message, (res) => {
    if(res === 0) {
      autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
    }
  })
})
.....
          autoUpdater.setFeedURL('https://my-update-server/path');
          autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
.....
```

then when I am pushing the build it will do everything correct with the latest.yml file generating but after installing I found the app-update.yml is not there ...

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I have the same problem.

Comment: Since OP has gone AWOL, @MehrshadFarzaneh and @HelloWorld, I solved this issue by simplifying things as much as possible, including the `npm` command + params, and the config files / sections. In my case, the issue was that I had some config in the `package.json` and some more in a separate json file, and depending on how I invoked npm, I got different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a problem with missing app-update.yml and dev-app-update.yml then paste the following code into index.js:

```
import path from "path"
import fs from "fs"
const feed = 'your_site/update/windows_64'

let yaml = '';

yaml += "provider: generic\n"
yaml += "url: your_site/update/windows_64\n"
yaml += "useMultipleRangeRequest: false\n"
yaml += "channel: latest\n"
yaml += "updaterCacheDirName: " + app.getName()

let update_file = [path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'app-update.yml'), yaml]
let dev_update_file = [path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'dev-app-update.yml'), yaml]
let chechFiles = [update_file, dev_update_file]

for (let file of chechFiles) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(file[0])) {
        fs.writeFileSync(file[0], file[1], () => { })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using `autoUpdater.setFeedURL()` before `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()`. Below is the code snippet that works for github releases. Also, please make sure there is existing release in Github before running this code.

```
import { autoUpdater } from "electron-updater";

// ...

autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
  provider: "github",
  owner: "org",
  repo: "repo",
});
```